Singularity in Poisson's Equation
Consider an instance of Poisson's equation in spherical coordinates for the radial dimension:
$$
\nabla \cdot \nabla \phi(r) = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2 \frac{d\phi}{dr} \right) = -\sin(r).
$$
The general solution be analytically calculated as
$$
\phi(r) = \sin(r) + 2\frac{\cos(r)}{r} + C_1 + \frac{C_2}{r}.
$$
Note how, regardless of boundary conditions, a singularity exists at the origin. This seems intuitive to me. In the application of Poisson's equation to model heat conduction from a distributed source, a source of the form $\sin(r)$ seems physically possible to me. However, a resulting temperature distribution with a singularity at the origin is not physically possible. How can this singularity at the origin be physically justifiable?
My Attempt at Understanding
Inspired by a potentially related question, consider the divergence theorem applied to the field $\nabla \phi$ for an infinitesimally small sphere around the origin:
$$
\iiint_V \nabla \cdot \nabla \phi(r) dV = \iint_S \left(\nabla \phi(r) \cdot \hat{\mathbf{r}}\right) dS
$$
This expression can be manipulated by substituting the rhs of Poisson's equation to $\nabla \cdot \nabla \phi(r)$ and performing the integration. Then, the rhs of this equation can be obtained analytically using the first integration step in Poisson's equation
$$
-4\pi \left(-2\delta r \sin(\delta r) + ((\delta r)^2 - 2)\cos(\delta r) + 2\right) = -4\pi\left( 2\frac{\sin(\delta r)}{\delta r} + 2 \frac{\cos(\delta r)}{(\delta r)^2} - \cos(\delta r) + \frac{C_2}{\delta r^2}\right)
$$
Now, take the limit as $\delta r \rightarrow 0$
$$
-4\pi \left(0 + (0 - 2) + 2\right) = -4\pi\left( 2(1) + 2 (\infty)- 1 + \infty \right)
$$
Regardless of boundary conditions, there is some conflict because
$$
0 = \infty.
$$
This result lines up with the mental block I am describing in the first part of this question.
